# How can I get an Angular component to invoke its child component?

Tags: angular

I have a component, SubjectComponent, which is declared in SubjectsModule as shown here:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    SubjectComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    BrowserModule,
    SubjectsRoutingModule
  ]
})
export class SubjectsModule { }
```

The path to SubjectComponent in AppRoutingModule is as follows:

```
{
   path: 'subject',
   loadChildren: () => import('./subjects/subjects.module').then(m => m.SubjectsModule)
 },
```

And the completion of the path to SubjectComponent is shown in SubjectsRoutingModule as follows:

```
const routes: Routes = [
{
   path: 'get/:grade/:gradeLabel',
   component: SubjectsComponent,
 },
 {
   path: 'gradeLabel/:gradeLabel/subjectId/:subjectId',
   component: SubjectComponent
 },  
];
@NgModule({
 imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
 exports: [RouterModule]
 })
 export class SubjectsRoutingModule { }
```

A call from SubjectsComponent.html to SubjectComponent is as follow:

```
<a *ngFor="let subject of subjects"                
    [routerLink]="['/subject', 'gradeLabel', gradeLabel, 'subjectId', subject._id]">
    <h1>{{subject.name}}</h1>
</a>
```

When this route is invoked, I get the following Angular error:

```
main.03b8d5569b0984a5.js:1 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: NG04002
Error: NG04002
at ga.noMatchError
```

However when I invoke the SubjectComponent route from HeaderComponent.html as a test as shown below, the route is found. It works.

```
<div class="ms-2">
    <a class="login secondary-color" 
    [routerLink]="['/subject', 'gradeLabel', 'Grade 9', 'subjectId', '63e2739b3dad93238da85918']">Testing</a>
  </div>
```

app.component.html

```
<app-header></app-header>
<app-message></app-message>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Comment: What happens if relative route is used in SubjectComponent? `['gradeLabel', gradeLabel, 'subjectId', subject._id]`

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do, but in general viewChild is needed to invoke a method of a child component in angular.

Comment: Apparently, others understand what I am trying to do, Rick, your semantic game notwithstanding. Thanks for playing, though.

Comment: Can you share your app.component.html? I'm assuming the  <router-outlet> tag is in  app.component.html?

Comment: I have added app.component.html to my original question.